# vector iterator in for loop

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have this loop

```
   for(vector<Graph*>::iterator itr = current->getchildren().begin(); itr = current->getchildren().end(); ++itr)
```

where current is :

```
   Graph* current = new Graph(*root);

    class Graph
    {
    private:

        vector<Graph*>              children;
```

I have this error on the loop :

> error: could not convert '(itr = (* &(&
>   current->Graph::getchildren())->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end >()))' from 'std::vector::iterator {aka
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' to 'bool'

I don't have any clue about what is wrong here. I've been using this loop in previous versions of the code without problem (only the name of current changed)

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: You could not be using it, because the second term in 'for' should be a Boolean expression, not an assignment. You stay in the cycle as long as that expression is evaluated as 'true'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing iterator to the end with `!=`:

```
for (...; itr != current->getchildren().end(); ...)
```

In your code you use assignement operator `=`  setting the value of your iterator immediately to the end.  This experssion had the type of an iterator, and fortunately, the compiler didn't find a way to convert it to a bool